# What is the physical implication or significance of a wave function being an eigenfunction of some operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, observables

I understand that if some wavefunction $\psi(x)$ is a an eigenfunction of some operator, say, momentum $-i \hbar \frac{d}{dx}$, then:

$$\hat{p}\psi(x)=p\psi(x) \equiv \hat{p}\left| \psi \right> = p \left| \psi \right>$$

$$\left< \psi | \hat{p} | \psi \right> = \left< \psi | p | \psi \right> = p \left< \psi | \psi \right> = p$$

Then that means that the eigenvalue $p$ is the expectation value of momentum. Cool.

That also therefore means that any linear combination of wavefunctions which are eigenfunctions of momentum with eigenvalue $p$ *also* have momentum $p$. Cool.

But what does that actually… mean? Why is this important? What sort of physical signficance can I ascribe to this? I'm not seeing why my textbooks and homeworks seem to place so much emphases on these eigenfunctions if I can't seem to find any reason why they are important.

Comment: Are your textbooks not talking about measurement and the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) at all? Which books *are* these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible values that can result from measuring an observable $\hat{O}$ is the observables spectrum $\sigma(\hat{O})$. The spectrum of an operator is the set of its eigenvalues (this is not completely true, but let's just ignore that here).

The states that describe a physical system are vectors in a Hilbert space H: $|\Psi\rangle \in H$. You can always find a complete set of eigenvectors of any observable. This allows you to write any vector $|\Psi\rangle \in H$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors

$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_n c_n |\Phi_n\rangle$, with $\hat{O}|\Phi_n\rangle = \lambda_n |\Phi_n\rangle$ and $c_n = \langle \Phi_n|\Psi\rangle$.

The $c_n$'s in the above sum have a physical meaning: When measuring $\hat{O}$, you will measure $\lambda_n$ with a probability of $|c_n|^2$ (this requires $\sum_n |c_n^2| = 1$).

So if the state of the system is described by an eigenvector of some observable $\hat{O}$ (e.g. $c_1 = 1$, and $c_n = 0\  \forall n\geq 2$), then you know with absolute certainty that the measurement of $\hat{O}$ will yield $\lambda_1$.

Comment: You can use $|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \psi|$ for the bra-ket notation.

Comment: But what is the Latex code to get bra's and ket's? I tried \ket{} but it didn't work.

Comment: See for example [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/should-we-indicate-the-use-of-renewcommand-in-the-help-center?noredirect=1&lq=1) and  [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/on-bra-ket-notation).

Answer (score 2):

It means you can use the eigenvalue *as a label* for the state since (in your example) $\Delta p=0$.  Not only is the average value $p$, but there is no fluctuation in this outcome.

Hence for instance we can *label* hydrogen states by energy, angular momentum, and projection because the eigenstates have “unique” (in the sense they do not fluctuate) values of these quantities.  We can speak of a state having *this energy*, with *this angular momentum* etc because if you mak a measurement of energy on such an eigenstate you get a single answer.